# How to control or manage JMS Queue? Eg. changing message order in Queue, Deleting message etc

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, jms, hornetq

I am using HornetQ with JBoss6 in Linux OS,
Can anybody tell me How can we control JMS Queue to delete message or changing the order
of the message, Details of  MessageConsumers connected with Queue?

Which approach is best for such requirement?
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A queue is a simple concept -- multiple sources write to the queue and a single consumer reads the messages, one by one, in the order they were received. Trying to introduce random access muddles the concept and goes contrary to the intent with a queue.

If you can't modify the consumer to delete or sort the messages, then introduce an intermediary queue and message driven bean (MDB) to do the work: The MDB will consume the messages on queue `Q`, discard certain messages and re-order other messages before publishing the messages to queue `Q'`.

Before:

```
Q -> orignal consumer
```

After:

```
Q -> your filtering and sorting MDB -> Q' -> original consumer
```

This preserves the intent of the components in your design and is in my opinion much easier to explain and understand.

**Edit**: Your MDB could look something like the example shown below (based on the Java Enterprise Edition 6 [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbpo.html)). The tutorial also contains information about packaging and deploying the MDB.

```
// MDB to consume messages on the original queue
@MessageDriven(mappedName="jms/IncomingQueue", activationConfig =  {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode",
                                  propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType",
                                  propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue")
    })
public class MyMDB implements MessageListener {
    @EJB
    private MessageFilter messageFilter;

    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        // pass on to MessageFilter bean for processing
        messageFilter.filter(message);
    }
}

// singleton bean to filter and sort messages, then re-publish to the original consumer
// if singleton doesn't work in your environment then you might have to persist the
// messages using e.g. JPA
@Singleton
public class MessageFilter {
    @Resource(name="jms/OutgoingQueue")
    Queue outgoingQueue;

    @Resource(name="jms/QueueConnectionFactory")
    QueueConnectionFactory qcf;

    // accept incoming message from the MDB
    void filter(Message message) {
        // filter and sort messages
        ...

        // send to queue read by the original consumer
        send(message);            
    }

    // send message to the filtered & sorted queue for the original consumer
    void send(Message message) {
        QueueConnection queueConnection = qcf.createQueueConnection();
        QueueSession queueSession = queueConnection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        QueueSender queueSender = queueSession(outgoingQueue);

        queueSender.send(message);
    }
}
```

The Java EE 6 tutorial also has examples on [how to create singleton beans](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipvi.html) and here's a [tutorial for connecting to a queue in order to send a message](http://developers.sun.com/appserver/reference/techart/tip1_june_2003.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Can you please give some more details for how to implement this thing with MDB? Do I need to use HornetQ Server API or any other approach for that?

Comment: @SmartSolution I've added a code example. I hope this helps. The Java Enterprise Edition 6 tutorial contains a wealth of information that explains the annotations and concepts I've introduced in the code above.

Comment: Thank you Kim, Can please look in this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289050/how-to-get-details-of-messagereceivers-of-jms-queuehornetq-deployed-in-jboss-as6