# How to get details of MessageReceivers of JMS Queue(HornetQ deployed in JBoss AS6)?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, jms, jmx, hornetq

I need to get details of Message Receivers which are connected to JMS Queue,
I am using HornetQ which is deployed in JBoss AS6.

Is there such operation/API already defined in JMX/JMS?
Any other approach to get details of MessageReceivers?
I need to know number of MessageReceivers & their IP Address.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are method on the management with hornetQ 2.2.2+. Things like connectionID are exposed as meta-datas.